# MVC Razor - Set default value for EditorFor as Today's Date

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make an `EditorFor`where it's value will be today's date, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

I've tried a couple things already, but none of them seem to work.

Attempt 1:

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Opgevoerd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "DateTime", placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", value=DateTime.Now } })
```

Attempt 2:

Controller:

```
Model.Opgevoerd = DateTime.Now;

return View(Computers___tabel);
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Opgevoerd,"{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "DateTime", placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy" } })
```

I don't remember attempt 3 x)

I've been stuck at this for quite a while and I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `value=DateTime.Now` to `Value=DateTime.Now`

Comment: `HtmlHelper` methods bind to your model. Set the value of `Opgevoerd` in the GET method and return the model to the view. - `model.Opgevoerd = DateTime.Now; return View(model);` Do NOT attempt to set the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @BrianAlltop but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke but that didn't work either x)

Comment: Of course it does. Edit you question to add the new code you have tried so we can fix your mistake

Answer (score 2):

After completely giving up on razor, I decided to fill the value of my `EditorFor` using javascript.

by doing:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
$('#opgevoerd').val(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy);
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Seriously? `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] public DateTime Opgevoerd { get; set; }`, set the value to `DateTime.Today;` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view and `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Opgevoerd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" })` (and why are you setting `type="DateTime"` when you only want a date component)

Comment: I set datetime because in the database it's set as datetime (I didnt make the data base) but my colleague only wanted the date. I'm relatively new to asp.net since I'm an intern so I didnt exactly know what you meant, I asked my supervisor and he told me to use javascript since opgevoerd isn't a model. it's an item inside a model. I'm sorry that I didn't do it your way.

Comment: A database (or model) `DataTime` type has absolutely nothing to do with the HTML-5 `type="datetime"` - its for generating the browsers HTML-5 datetimepicker (which only has limited browser support). Not only do you not need javascript - its stupid to do so (consider what happens when the use enters a value but you need to return the view - what the user typed in will be lost). And I know `Opgevoerd` is a property in your model - it would not work if it wasn't :)